# How to deliver to Front-end developers the behavior spec of a component?

Tags: user-behavior, frontend-development, use-cases

I am working on a new "component" for the company product that I work. The component is like an expansion panel which will have some call to actions that the user has to complete. This actions, the description of the action and the titles will change depending on what stage the user is, like initial state, pending state and approved. So my question is, how to communicate this states to developers because is like how is the behavior of the expansion panel on the different states I am not sure if I have to created different uses cases to solve question from them like "What happen if the user do this?" "What happen if the user do this another thing plus this" **I don't know how to deliver that information to developers.** in uses cases? in a table on a document in word? This is an example of the "cases" so the component will change depending of the case:

CASE 1: User choose UPLOAD ID,  has to wait to be upgraded to KYC1 and notified that his ID was approved.

CASE 2: User choose UPLOAD ID but decide in the same session to try with another option. He tries to Add a top up card and his card is not 3D secure, so he has to do the microtransaction and wait for the code.

CASE 3: User choose UPLOAD ID but decide in the same session to try with another option. He tries to Add a top up card and his card is 3D SECURE, so he is updated to KYC1 and will be notified about his ID that was approved on the notification bell.

Thank you! I hope I explain me well.

Comment: Possibly a bit non UX, but another angle on documentation is both functional testing and usability testing:  poor documentation makes it difficult to understand how software is supposed to work, so its difficult to test.

Comment: If you're worried about the interactions that lead to particular states you could always put together a prototype (or a few) to demonstrate what happens in each journey - Use something like InVision (https://www.invisionapp.com/), or Marvel (https://marvelapp.com/).

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes, I am worried about how to communicate this to developers, so then they are not going to ask "What happen if...?" so I can give to them all the specifications they need. I wasn't sure if is better with just a prototype or to deliver to them a document or something. Thanks!

Comment: as a developer, I would prefer if you were able to sit down with me and answer all my questions (together with whatever specification is necessary from the project management perspective)

Comment: Hi Aprillion, thank you for your answer! that is good, well I am always there for developers, the problem in my company is that we are not delivering any documentation for developers, just users stories :( because the manager think that because we are doing "scrum" people don't need nothing, but I think people need something a part to be available for any questions they have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototyping a complex control or UI element can be very useful if you intend to walk people through that prototype, but it is not a great "handoff" deliverable for conveying all possible use cases: that would require the recipient to play around and just "discover" the different use cases, unless you provided a script (which is an option).

We often describe these things in wireframe documents that we post in a shared space (Confluence for us right now), and describe page elements and interactions in a sidebar:
[image]

As old-school and text-heavy as use case documents can be, you might consider creating a section of some document for each discrete use case, and then describe the primary flow with representative screen shots, as well as alternate flows with their screen shots:

[image: Use Case and Flow documents]
In many of these the flow steps link to full-page prototypes

Actual animation or interaction aspects could be described, or if you deliver this document online you could create animated gifs that depict the interactions:

[image]

There are a lot of ways to do it, but however you hand off and whatever your documentation is, **there's no substitute for face-to-face communication and sitting down to work on things together with your developer** if at all possible!

Comment: Useful.  Particularly the annotated wireframe approach.

Comment: Thank you very much Mattynabib! very useful the options, I can see how others do so I can take the way is better for us, is a very good idea also to put this on a shared space for everybody involved on the project.